# Designing DB table that could refer to multiple other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

## Setup

I have two Postgres 10 tables for things that are somewhat similar but far from identical:

```
MotorVehicles
 Id (auto-incrementing int)
 PaintColor (varchar; not null)
 EngineSize (int; not null)
 Capacity (int)
```

and

```
Trailers
 Id (auto-incrementing int)
 PaintColor (varchar; not null)
 AttachedVehicle (int; not null; foreign key referring to MotorVehicles Id)
 Capacity (int)
```

Both are things on the road, and have some attributes in common, although one is clearly attached to the other (a truck could have multiple trailers and—at least for my purposes—a trailer shouldn't exist by itself).

I'm trying to design a table of things that can apply to either a `MotorVehicle` or a `Trailer`: `LicensePlates`.

```
LicensePlates
 PlateNumber (varchar; not null)
 Issuer (varchar)
 ExpirationDate (timestamp)
 ... some kind of reference to the above tables ...
```

I'm not sure how to finish the `LicensePlates` table up, because there's no unique identifier between `MotorVehicles` and `Trailers` (e.g. they could each have a row with ID number 1, and those things would not be the same, so I can't just have a `ParentId` attribute in `LicensePlates`).

### Constraints

Any given LicensePlate-type row *must* refer to *exactly one* MotorVehicle or Trailer, but not both, and not neither. However, a given MotorVehicle or Trailer *may* have multiple license plates (say, one from a Canadian province and one from a European country); or even no plates at all (if it's fresh out of the factory and not yet registered, or in storage).

### Options

**How should I actually design `LicensePlates`?** I've come up with a few options:

- Combine `MotorVehicles` and `Trailers` into a single `ThingsOnTheRoad` table so the IDs don't conflict

  - I'm against doing this because each existing table has some attributes that don't make semantic sense for the other, plus this would interfere with constraints
- In `LicensePlates`, save the ID from the relevant table in one column, and the table it's referring to in another column

  - This seems the most straightforward, but also pretty inelegant.
- Create an auto-incrementing column that spans both tables, so there would never be an ID number conflict

  - From [what I've read](https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/10/04/sharing-an-auto_increment-value-across-multiple-mysql-tables/), this isn't actually possible, plus there might be headaches down the line figuring out which table the ID belonged to anyways even though it's unique
- Replace the existing autoincrementing IDs with GUIDs

  - Could work, but messes with human-readability
- Somehow merge the `MotorVehicles` and `Trailers` in a view to get all the benefits of the second option but none of the downsides

  - This seems appealing, but I don't have the foggiest idea of how to actually set it up

So what do I actually do? Is there another option I haven't listed? In particular, *is it possible to set up the view I mentioned last, and if so, how?*

(As you've probably guessed, these aren't my real tables, but they do simulate the important points of the relationship.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second option is perfect, it is known as polymorphic relations. The concept which I used widely in my few rails applications for such requirements.

In short, `LicencePlates` table should have two columns, `VehicleID` and `VehicleType`. Where `VehicleID` stores id of `MotorVehicles` or `Trailers` and `VehicleType` can refer to table from which the id is being referred to.

This approach has many advantages.

1. Explicitness - You know which table is being referred to, and id.
2. Simplicity - It is pretty straightforward, you don't have to manage IDs, GUIDs, their sequences etc. DBs are good at managing certain things such as IDs, use it, don't underestimate it.
3. Maintainability - Not just at code level, but also concept of attaching - detaching LicencePlate to a particular resource (Trailer / MotorVehicle) is easy to maintain. Both are vehicles running on road, but will have different uses, access pattern, information, validations and much more.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has just the thing you need [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/tutorial-inheritance.html).

Basically, both `trailers` and `movingvehicles` should be derived from another table -- say `licensablevehicles`.

Then, you can have a foreign key relationship either to your two original tables or to `licensablevehicles`.

Comment: I came across a solution like this a little while ago, and didn't realize it was so well supported in Postgres. I don't think it works for me, though; per the [expanded documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-inherit.html), "A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply to single tables, not to their inheritance children." So, setting a primary key in `licensablevehicles` wouldn't prevent collisions between `trailers` and `motorvehicles`.